# Android camera to take multiple photos

Tags: java, android, mysql

The **problem** class:

```
    public class problem extends Activity {

        ImageView iv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.problem);

    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });
            }

         @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bm=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
       iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
           }    
           }
```

This is what I wanted to do:

- Take multiple photos
- show them in the screen
- store them in the mysql databse.

I am new to android please tell me how to do that.I searched.But I could not find a answer. 
From this code IT TAKE ONLY ONE PHOTO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show Image on Screen Before Saving :

Use my Code. I am taking a picture using camera intent and before saving it to gallery , it is showed to the user with a Save and Cancel Button :- Call Camera Intent :-

```
// This code is to call the camera intent. Basically it will start your camera. Put this code in a button or something                        
String SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +CommonFunction.getDateTime()+".jpg"; // Get File Path
                        Intent takePictureFromCameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        takePictureFromCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR)));
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureFromCameraIntent, 123);
```

onActivityResult : -

```
// This function is called when you come back to your activity after the intent has finished. Do read android documentation on Google. It will Help
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) 
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {
            String galleryImatePath = SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR; // make SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR Global so that you can access it here from camera intent or pass it in put Extra method and retrieve it here
            File f = new File(galleryImatePath);

            try {//This code will rotate your image if you have taken the image by rotating the camera
                        Bitmap cameraBitmap = null;
                        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
                        bmOptions.inBitmap = cameraBitmap; 
                        bmOptions.inMutable = true; 


                        cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(galleryImatePath,bmOptions);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        cameraBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);

                        //To Rotate image Code
                            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(galleryImatePath);
                            float rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);  
                            System.out.println(rotation);

                        float rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
                        System.out.println(rotationInDegrees);

                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(rotationInDegrees);

                        final Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap , 0, 0, cameraBitmap.getWidth(), cameraBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(galleryImatePath);
                        rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos);
                        fos.write(bos.toByteArray());
                        cameraBitmap.recycle();
                        System.gc();
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();


                        // To set image in imageview in dialog. This code will set your image in a custon dialog box "captiondialog". It will contain a full width and height imageview and two textviews - done and cancel. It is upto u what you want to define in the textview's click listener. For example, you can pass the storing image in database in the "Done" textview and "Cancel" textview will dismiss your captiondialog and you app will return to your activity
                    Capdialog = new Dialog(AddToDo.this,android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                    Capdialog.setContentView(R.layout.captiondialog);
                    Capdialog.setCancelable(false);
                    TextView cancel = (TextView) Capdialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                    TextView done = (TextView) Capdialog.findViewById(R.id.done);
                                                Capdialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                    ImageView img = (ImageView) Capdialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
               }
               catch(Exception e){}
      }
 }
}
```

implement your done and cancel on click listener - what you want to do in them. My code will capture your image, rotate it in the right direction irrespective of camera rotation and show it to you in a dialog before saving it

This code will store your image in DB.You have to use "blob" to store image.. Use This Code :-
public void insertImageInDb(int id , Bitmap img ) {

```
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray(); // Use This or the code in comments below

/*  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();*/

insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;
```

}

There's an alternative intent action for the device camera that launches the camera in still image mode and does not exit until the user is finished with the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
    MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Used with a ContentObserver this was exactly what I needed to accomplish. or Handle this in ActivityResult.

Note :- if you are new to android, this is too hard for you to understand now. Please read the android documentation first on google and read tutorials. Make basic apps. Learn first

Comment: Can you explain above code with details. It is hard to understand because I am new to android.

Comment: @user2975407 - I have edited my code and added details comments explaining the code. However, i would suggest your read the android documentation and tutorials first on Android

Comment: CommonFunction means what?

Comment: -anyway thanks for your help.I'll read the documentation first.

Comment: @Rahul-thanks for your help.